# A/B testing with conversion rate higher than 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, marketing

I encountered the following issue with A/B testing.

Imagine that you have a website where visitor are crazy and that they buy a lot of items each time they visit. The conversion rate of each version is higher than one. However I still want to know whether my new website is more appealing than before, so I'd like to do a Z-test or a chi-squared test. But these tests are only possible when the conversion rate is smaller than 1. However, I saw on this blog post https://vwo.com/blog/how-to-calculate-ab-test-sample-size/ that this Z-score corresponds to the common space between the two Gaussian...

My question is: Is there a way to compute a statistical significance of this comparison between conversion rate that are higher than 1?

Thank you very much

Comment: How do your define conversion rate (in order to get values > 1)? Depending on definition, maybe OK to use t test to compare A and B rates. But maybe more informative to compare _dollar amounts_ of purchases.

Comment: Conversion rate is defined as number of purchase/ number of visit. So when a visitor is purchasing a lot of items conversion rate is bigger than one.